# Drop down menu with checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, drop-down-menu

I have problem with drop down menu in WPF because I want to code this menu like this:

[image: ComboBox with CheckBox items and details]

But I'm struggling with it and I only managed to do something like this:

[image: ComboBox with plain CheckBox items]

So I'm wondering if someone could help me to make it look more like in the first example.

Style (XAML):

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ContextMenu}" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                    <Border Background="#ff2e2f33"  Opacity="1" Width="190">
                        <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" Height="30" Background="#FF2E2F33" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Text="Kategorie" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <Button  Height="30" Width="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle2}" Name="buttonCategory" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button1_Click" Margin="168,114,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="White" >
        <Button.Content>
            <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Category 1" Template="{DynamicResource CustomCheckBox}" />
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Category 2" Template="{DynamicResource CustomCheckBox}" />
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Category 3" Template="{DynamicResource CustomCheckBox}" />
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Category 4" Template="{DynamicResource CustomCheckBox}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

C# code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (sender as Button);
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

    }
```

Comment: What _specifically_ is preventing you from achieving the look you want? As written, your question seems to simply be asking for someone else to write the code for you. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what happened and how that's different from what you want. The pictures certainly help, but they are no substitute for a well-written question with a good code example.

Comment: I have problem with 3 things mouseOver effect , space between the textbox and drop down ContextMenu(cause setting margin don't work)  + placing that little arrow on top of ContextMenu rectangle.Some tips ?